# Django: apply filtering on model imported from external library

Tags: django, django-filter

Is it possible to apply easy filtering to a list of object retrieved from an API, without having a model in my Django app? I can import the model of the retrieved objects from an external library, but I don't have a Django model in my apps for them.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom filtering using `django-filters` just add the external library model in `Meta` class and add the fields on which you need filtering.

Another way, would be to get filter value from query parameter and do filtering on queryset obtained of the external model field.